# Snap binary files upload

Tags: haskell-snap-framework

I need to understand the file uploading process with Snap.

Given this form:

```
<form id="form" action="/files/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
  <button type="submit"  onclick="handleFiles(e)">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Do I use the same functions like getPostParams to process binary files or do I use functions from Snap.Util.FileUploads?

I need to upload and save binary files like PDF in the database. The database driver will accept a ByteString to store a binary file.

I went through the Snap.Util.FileUploads but it does not look like it is what I need. 
So I am not sure how to process this in the handler?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

With some help from IRC I managed to come up with the below construct. I think it should be close to correct?? Well, it compiles and dumps the file to mongodb. I can also read it back. Although I don't quite understand the enumerators and Iteratee stuff ...

```
handleFiles :: AppHandler ()
handleFiles = do
  [file] <- handleMultipart defaultUploadPolicy $ \part -> do
    content <-  liftM BS.concat EL.consume
    return content
  let b = ["file" =: Binary file]
  r <- eitherWithDB $ insert "tests" b
  either (error . show) (const $ return () ) r
```

Answer (score 4):

Use Snap.Util.FileUploads.  It's quite tricky to get file uploading right without leaving yourself open to security vulnerabilities.  That FileUploads module has been carefully designed with this in mind.

The docs describe [`handleFileUploads`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/snap-core/0.9.4.0/doc/html/Snap-Util-FileUploads.html#v%3ahandleFileUploads) pretty well.  It "reads uploaded files into a temporary directory and calls a user handler to process them."  You supply it with a handler with the type:

```
[(PartInfo, Either PolicyViolationException FilePath)] -> m a
```

`handleFileUploads` stores all the incoming files on disk subject to the policy you specify.  Then it calls your handler and passes it the list of files handled.

Comment: Thank you. I thought I could control the security of the incoming file size, type etc. via html5 File API on the client side. At least for now... Maybe I just did not get how handleFileUploads function works. I have an incoming ByteString so my handler should be able to grab the ByteString and pass it to the database driver as ByteString. handleFileUploads function takes a handler as a parameter which in turn takes PartInfo and Either FilePath. So which FilePath are we talking about? How does it take the ByteString coming from the browser? Could you explain how handleFileUploads works?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I updated my question with a possible correct use of the handleMultipart function. I suppose, the handleFileUploads usage should be similar.